# how to convert datetime from any zone to a specific zone in mysql

Tags: mysql, convert-tz

I have a mySQL table with a date recorded from various different Time Zones.  How can I convert the DateTime value to the viewing user TimeZone while doing a SELECT statement in mySQL ?

```
    SELECT ClientID,
        convert_tz(MessageDate,???,???)
        MeetingType,
        MeetingDate,
        Comments,
        CompanyName
    FROM clientCompNotes
    WHERE ClID = 970392281 AND CompanyID=411972145
```

The problem is to accept any timezone from the date recorded in the "MessageDate" field, which looks like this

```
 Wed May 30 2012 12:51:02 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Many thanks

Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do this.  MySQL will perform timezone conversion for you, provided that you store your times in `TIMESTAMP` type columns and that you set the session `time_zone` variable appropriately.  As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/time-zone-support.html):

> The MySQL server maintains several time zone settings:
>
> [...]
>
> - Per-connection time zones. Each client that connects has its own time zone setting, given by the session [`time_zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone) variable. Initially, the session variable takes its value from the global [`time_zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone) variable, but the client can change its own time zone with this statement:
>
>   ```
>   mysql> SET time_zone = timezone;
>   ```
>
> The current session time zone setting affects display and storage of time values that are zone-sensitive. This includes the values displayed by functions such as [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) or [`CURTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime), and values stored in and retrieved from [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) columns. Values for [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) columns are converted from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
>
> The current time zone setting does not affect values displayed by functions such as [`UTC_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp) or values in [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html), [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/time.html), or [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) columns. Nor are values in those data types stored in UTC; the time zone applies for them only when converting from `TIMESTAMP` values. If you want locale-specific arithmetic for [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html), [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/time.html), or [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) values, convert them to UTC, perform the arithmetic, and then convert back.

Answer (score 1):

```
CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)
```

The `from_tz` is the timezone in which the time currently is in and `to_tz` is the one in which you want to convert it to.

Comment: That's not what I asked.  The timezone is already recorded in the DatTime and I don't want to have to manipulate it.  I want to do a direct convert from ANY zone recorded in the field itself... Look at the GMT-0400 in the example

Comment: But I have to estimate which "from_tz" to enter into the second parameter.  And I want to let the function guess which tz the datetime is without my help, @Juniad.

Comment: I get a NULL back as result with CONVERT_TZ(MessageDate,'UTC','GMT') and any other incarnation! And this is the way it is stored: Wed May 30 2012 12:51:02 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)